# Unable to execute script from c# using smo

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, winforms

I have developed a C# Windows application in which I need to create a database on client machine for which I have created a script file and installed SQL Server 2008 R2 on client machine.

But when I execute script from my code it always shows an error:

> Failed to connect database.

I have added referenced the SMO assemblies from

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\90\SDK\Assemblies\Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo.dll
```

And my code is :

```
string sqlConString = @"Integrated Security=SSPI;Persist Security Info=False;Initial Catalog=mydatabase;Data Source=(local)";
FileInfo file = new FileInfo(dbPath);

string script = file.OpenText().ReadToEnd();

SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(sqlConString);

Server server = new Server(new ServerConnection(con));
server.ConnectionContext.ExecuteNonQuery(script);

file.OpenText().Close();
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about something like this:

```
using (SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection(sqlConString))
{
    var cmds = File.ReadAllText(@"path\to\file").Split(new string[] { "GO" },
        StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

    cnn.Open();
    foreach (var cmd in cmds)
    {
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(cmd, cnn))
        {
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
}
```

With this approach you get what you want, the script gets executed, but you don't have to use the slow and bloated SMO interface. Further, you're leveraging the `using` statement so you don't have to worry about unmanaged resources being left open.

Now, to address the `failed to connect to database...`, which I clearly missed the first time I read it, if that's happening that means this:

```
Initial Catalog=mydatabase;Data Source=(local)
```

is **likely** not right. And if it is, your server may not be accepting [Windows Authentication](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188670.aspx).

I don't know the setup of your local machine, but it's likely that the server is `(local)\SQLEXPRESS`.

Comment: i have tried this one it not works for me. Problem with this is there is lot of table creation in my script so end of every script there is GO statement s its showing incorrect syntax near GO.

Comment: @Raghubar, okay, this is a pretty simple problem to solve. Please see my edit.

Comment: The first statement splits the entire script file into an array of strings. Then you see me looping through that array of strings (i.e. the script text between `GO` statements) and executing each one individually.

Comment: this is working but problem is only four or five table is created every time not more than that.

Comment: @Raghubar, please post the script **up to the point at which it fails** plus a few more lines in your question so I can see the actual text I'm working with.

Comment: ??? This solution will fail as soon as there is a GO some where in SQL. Think about "insert into GOALS(id,title) values('GO01','MY GOAL')"

Comment: Nice answer from Michael. But I get an error because the connection is already open. Move the cnn.Open() statement above the foreach loop. Also, the full path to the file should be in the parentheses in File.ReadAllText().